# Wordpress - Custom Post Type & Custom Field Issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I seem to be getting nowhere with this.

I have custom post types set up as Areas.

I'm trying to call all pages under the CPT "areas" into a select box.

```
<form action="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
<select name="page_id" id="page_id">
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'show_option_none' => __( 'None' ),
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'post_type'=>'areas',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'suppress_filters' => true);
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<option value="<? echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
```

This code works but cancels out other custom fields being called further on down the page.

For example, this bit of code works if the other code is removed:

```
<img src="<?php
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mainimg', true)) {
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mainimg', true);
}
?>">
```

I'd really appreciate any help. I have no idea what's causing this issue. The closest I came was thinking it's to do with the post ID part but I am genuinely at a loss.

Thank you in advance.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Huseyin

Changed `$post to $post2`

Also changed `<?php the_title(); ?> to <?php echo $post2->post_title; ?>` as Wordpress was showing the current page title for all options.

Comment: Change the name in foreach: 

foreach( $posts as $post2 ) : setup_postdata($post2); ?>
<option value="<? echo $post2->ID; ?>">

Comment: @Huseyin - It seems that fixes the issue but the option value options on the front end loads the correct post ID and link but the name displays the post title for all other areas.

For example

Option 1: Southampton
Option 2: Southampton (links to Portsmouth page)